# Tomcat sometimes doesn't render the page and shows plain HTML

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, webserver

I have a J2EE App and I've been running it for a couple of years...

recently there's chance that whatever page I want to visit, it may show up as just Plain HTML and may not be rendered...

No Logs are written about this behavior as if it's a normal thing...

usually I click to visit a page, the Browser shows some cue about sending the request to the server... I can check that everything works just fine back there... Now there's 2 ways I can see this error :

**1.** I wait and wait and wait... and the browser is still waiting for a response... If I lose patience and press F5, the page shows up as PlainText HTML.

**2.** I wait till the end and the Browser may or may not load the page... if it loads the page, it's only partial and some parts of the Javascript or HTML may not load at all.

Pressing F5 usually fixes the problem but after a while, this may happen again...

This used to happen with Tomcat 6.x every once in a while but became worse after using Tomcat 7.x .

at first I thought it's related to my App but then I noticed this pattern happening even in Tomcat's own Admin pages such as its Session Manager.

What can I do ? I'm using Tomcat 7.0.54. upgrading it to newer versions didn't help...

Thank you...

Comment: You're not setting the mimetype to HTML in the servlet probably.

Comment: Then why doesn't it always happen ? (I'm not at work right now but as soon as I get my hands on the code, I'll try your advice)